# Python: How to access a diagonal in reverse in a matrix?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a tic tac toe program, and I need to return a diagonal in a 3x3 matrix.

Say my board looks like this:

```
board = [
    ["a", "x", "b"],
    ["c", "o", "d"],
    ["e", "f", "g"]
]
```

I have for the forward matrix:

```
diag = [board[i][i] for i in range(len(board))]
```

which returns:

```
>>> diagonal(board, 1)
['a', 'o', 'g']
```

(If possible can someone explain to me why this works. I'm not so good with comprehending lists...).

How would I go about getting the reverse? say, `['b', 'o', 'e']`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your board is a list that contains three items, which are also lists. Therefore, `i` will iterate from 0 to 2 inclusive. By calling board[i][i], you are calling three commands:
`board[0][0]`,
`board[1][1]`,
`board[2][2]`.
In a basic 1D list, board[0] will refer to the first element, board[1] to the second, etc.
With your 2D array, in the command `board[0][0]`, you are calling the first element of the first element of the board (so basically `"a"`). Next, you are moving to the right one step and the bottom one step, and you are calling the second element of the second element of the board (`"o"`). This is the logic behind the code.

To get the other diagonal, you have to use:

```
diag = [board[i][len(board) - 1 - i] for i in range(len(board))]
```

This means instead of calling `board[0][0]`, you are calling `board[0][3 - 1 - 0]`, which is `board[0][2]`. The next iteration will call `board[1][1]`, and the next `board[2][0]`. You first subtract 1 from the length, because length counting starts from 1 (e.g., there are three elements in your board, `len(board) = 3`), while indexing starts at 0 (`board[0][3]` does not exist, only `board[0][0]`, `board[0][1]`, and `board[0][2]`).
Hope this helps!

Comment: Everyone had super helpful answers but this one totally makes sense for me! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your row will increment as 1st case only. Only the column indexing will change. you will start from end and move towards left by decrementing it.

For forward diagonal: You are taking the location where your `(row_index==col_index) => (0,0) , (1,1), (2,2)`

For Reverse: 
start with the end and move towards left side.

Try:

```
diag = [board[i][len(board)-1-i] for i in range(len(board))]
```

---

```
['b', 'o', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to get diagonal elements you can do the following.

For leading diagonal :

`leading_diagonal = [ row[i] for i,row in enumerate(board) ]`

For counter diagonal:

`counter_diagonal = [ row[-i-1] for i,row in enumerate(board) ]`

In above approach it goes through each row counting its index at `i` and takes `row[i]` which is true as for `0th` row, the element will be `0` and so on.
For counter diagonal, it takes `row[-i-1]` where `-i-1` is `-(i+1)`. In Python list  `-` actually means to take element from last.

Other solution is by using `lambda` and `map` function :

For leading diagonal :

`leading_diagonal = list(map(lambda x: x[board.index(x)], board))`

For counter diagonal:

`counter_diagonal = list(map(lambda x: x[(len(board) - 1) - board.index(x)], board))`